# Nest execute commands in bash

Tags: bash, shell, nested, quotes

I am trying to associate a hotkey with opening vim with recent history browsing, thus I have wrote the following line

```
gnome-terminal -x "vim -c ':browse old'"
```

However this gives

```
Error: Failed to execute child process "vim -c ':browse old'" (No such file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! The `-x` option of `gnome-terminal` makes it very easy to start a new terminal and run a new program in it. Just do:

```
gnome-terminal -x vim -c ':browse old'
```

The meaning of `-x` is that all subsequent arguments are passed to the program that you run, so no quoting is needed.